# Url fragment is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.NET MVC3, the url `http://localhost:22713/tests#123456` with the following code:

```
Your user agent: @Request.UserAgent<br />
Url: @Request.Url.AbsoluteUri<br />
Url fragment: @Request.Url.Fragment<br />
```

returns:

```
Your user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 
Url: http://localhost:22713/tests 
Url fragment:
```

Why is fragment always empty? I need to be able to parse this info on the server side.

Comment: #fragments are intended for the client and are not sent on the querystring to the server, so why Microsoft has included it I do not know. from http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/dfdb20ae-b335-48ae-a201-f2a5a8329342/how-do-i-get-paths-and-url-fragments-from-the-httprequest-object.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fragment (everything after the # in a url) doesn't get passed to the server. So the `Fragment` property will always be empty when you attempt to get it from a request.

The `Fragment` property is typically only used when constructing URLs.

There's no easy way to get the fragment on the server. Typically you would have to use javascript to retrieve the fragment.

Comment: I faced it with Facebook login integration (when user authenticated your application), so I must redirect to a "middle page" where JavaScript code get access_code fragment and then posting back to server.